# Tabs to spaces in BBEdit

Tags: macos, text-editor, bbedit

How can I configure BBEdit to insert 4 spaces (or at least spaces up to the next column which is a multiple of 4)? I've checked "Auto-expand tabs" in the preferences, but it doesn't seem to be doing that.

Comment: @Alexander I can think of one reason like when you push code to github.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Auto-expand tabs preference must also be set for the Language mapping setting. Also, the setting won't be applied until you create or open a new document.

See `Languages` in BBEdit.

Comment: Ah, I needed to create/open a document, that was it. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! This was driving me insane because tabs mess up anything I paste from BBEdit into a Rails console

Answer (score 21):

This has stymied me for quite some time, and today I found the way to enable this for open documents. At the very top of the Document in BBEdit in the left hand corner, you will find the path of the file you are currently editing immediately preceded by a small gear icon. Click the gear icon and place a check in the box next to "Auto-expand Tabs".

Comment: Though useful to note, perhaps, that it appears that you still have to hit settings to make this permanent.

Comment: I love this answer! And FWIW, there's a *bonus* feature included with this setting: when the cursor is positioned at the end of the "tab" (now 4 spaces), a single <kbd>delete</kbd> removes all 4 spaces. So, you can actually have your cake, and eat it too!